# Massive volcano on reef world?

Tags: planets, geography, geology

Piggybacking on my previous question:
[Possible reef world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201259/possible-reef-world)

An answer in that question included that reef world is an "old, old world. (So)The core has frozen and plate tectonics have stopped..."

*But*, I wanted to add an environmental complication for my explorers to encounter in the form of a volcano.

What if before the core finally freezes there is one massive Olympus Mons type volcano on reef worlds only land mass that erupts? Is it possible that could be the last gasp of the planet shedding its interior heat?

And for added drama I wouldn't mind if that event were a potential planet killer...? But it doesn't have to be.

Comment: I was thinking of environmental complications on a reef world.  I was thinking of something biological, like a worm bloom or red tide.  The Pern series had similar - "Thread".  The Xanth series had wiggles.  Maybe make an environmental threat that matches the world you have made?

Comment: @Willk Thanks for your thoughts. Great minds think alike? I was already thinking of a conflict between Sargasso and Reef. Apparently they don't get along.

Comment: I was actually thinking of something more spectacular, to substitute for the volcano.

Comment: @Willk MORE spectacular than an active Olympus Mons on a shallow water world?!

Comment: Yeah.  Something alive and interested.

Comment: @Willk I have been thinking about what kind of life could be native to Reef World...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.
That is basically what Olympus Mons is.
A rather ordinary shield volcano, formed over a rather ordinary mantle plume, on a planet where plate tectonics have ground to a halt.

So the volcano just sputters away in the exact same spot for many millions of years, building up a rather impressive mound in the process.

Obviously the core cannot be *frozen*, but the crust could have cooled sufficiently thickly to just not move around any more.

For the added drama... The volcano has now gone dormant. Not by choking on itself, but by having its magma channels and main chamber subsiding to deep underground.
But it's a mostly water world, so the water is entering this mosty-emptied magma chamber.

Just what happens if a couple dozen cubic kilometers of seawater get heated to well past its boiling point in the chamber, and the chamber then cracks?
This is what happened at Krakatau, back in 1883. Just smaller. Much smaller.

Comment: Uh oh! *Krakatoa Is Still Active, and We Are Not Ready for the Tsunamis Another Eruption Would Generate
By Ravindra Jayaratne, University of East London Feb 7, 2021* Not good!

Answer (score 3):

### Not On Its Own

The main problem with this scenario is that planets tend to solidify from the outside in. Today, the core of Mars is still molten, but there are no active volcanoes, as the crust is too thick. If the world were so old that the entire core had solidified, any magma that could have reached the surface would have solidified long ago.

### "Help" From an Asteroid

However, if the planet in your scenario still had a molten core, but the crust had grown too thick to allow plate tectonics or volcanism, a massive impact could still punch through the crust down to the mantle, allowing one last surge of volcanism. However, the sort of asteroid impact that could achieve this would be catastrophic for the planet. A roughly spherical nickel-iron meteorite will dig a crater with a depth about 3 times the impactor's diameter into the crust, and the continental crust on earth today, where plate tectonics are still active, has an average thickness of 125km. You could reduce the size of this impactor if it hit in the shallow ocean instead of on the last planetary landmass (the resulting volcanism might even create that landmass) but you're still talking about an asteroid impact orders of magnitude more powerful than the one that exterminated the dinosaurs (Chicxulub: 10-15km diameter, 30km deep crater). It wouldn't quite be a planet-killer, but it would threaten the extermination of all life on that planet.

Mercury was struck by an impactor about 100km in diameter, which could potentially have achieved the results you're after. Not only did that impact leave a massive crater, but the seismic waves converging on the far side of the planet tore up the surface creating "wierd terrain" (that is apparently the actual term). The floor of the crater is a flat plain, which may indicate that it punched clean through to the mantle and was filled by lava.