# Procedural Atmosphere for exoplanet - pseudorealistic composition, pressure etc

Tags: planets, atmosphere, gas

I have a programme built in python and rust, procedurally generating stars, planets, etc.

I have come to a point where I have to work on atmospheric characteristics, hopefully managing to get a pseudo-realistic outcome in terms of:

- composition/constituents in terms of substance
- surface pressure
- equilibrium temperature
- surface temperature
- total mass of atmosphere
- etc

Where pressure and temperature determine the states of the atmosphere constituents.

For example, I have just generated an atmosphere composed on the following approximate percentages:

- Methane 51%
- Ammonia 38%
- Nitrogen (N2) 4%
- Water 4%
- and negligible traces of other gases

And with the following characteristics outcome:

- equilibrium temperature: 152 K
- surface temperature: 200 K
- surface pressure: 21497.75 Pa, 0.21 atm

For a terrestrial planet ~0.55 the radius of earth and ~0.23 the mass of earth. Bond albedo is assumed to be 0.3.

Now to try and determine the state of the constituents, (solid/liquid/gas) I try and use Clausius-Clapeyron equation, shuffled around a bit so I can find the fusion and vaporisation points of each constituent under the given pressure and temperature:

```
Tf2 = 1 / (1/T1 - R . ln(P2/P1) / ΔHfus)
```

and

```
T2v = 1 / (1/T1 - R . ln(P2/P1) / ΔHvap)
```

where:

- T1 is the fusion/vaporisation temperature at pressure P1 = 101325 Pa for the given substance
- P2 is the "simulated" surface pressure for the planet
- T2f: is the fusion point for the substance given the "environment"
- T2v: is the vaporisation point for the substance given the "environment"

In the example above, this results (for water) as the following:

- `T2f = 172.18K`
- `T2v = 333.55K`

which means water will be liquid at the surface of this planet.

And while I am not looking for absolutely correct numbers (speed is more important than absolute correctness), I once in a while get the numbers for the following *other* example planet:

- planet radius: 1.82 earth
- planet mass: 4.14 earth (so some kind of super earth)
- T2 = 350 K
- P2 = 12538738.28 Pa, 123.75 atm
- T1 = 273.0 K / 373 K
- P1 = 101325 Pa
- Water heat of fusion: 6010.0 J/mol (at 273 K)
- Water heat of vaporisation: 40657.0 J/mol (at 373 K)

and then these values

- water melts at `-333.02 K` **(yes! negative Kelvin)**
- water boils at `589.75 K` (probably more realistic given the huge pressure!)

Obviously, getting negative K is far beyond the level of "pseudo" in "pseudorealistic".

**So my question is; what am I forgetting and handling badly?**
Critical temperature? Critical pressure? Both? Variable heat of fusion and heat of vaporisation?

I have read that

> Note that the enthalpies of fusion and vaporization change with
> temperature.

I am thinking to take that into account, assuming it would be the right thing to do? **But is it?**

---

Edit: I am not a physicist/chemist by trade or training... just a coder with a side project :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your planet is not a super earth, it's a gas giant. A rough estimate is that surface gravity given your size and mass is 12G. Surface gravity of Jupiter is 2.528 G

Comment: If you haven't already, keep in mind that atmospheric composition is not really a free variable. It depends heavily on the mass/gravity of the planet and the temperature and proximity of its sun.
See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201667/placing-a-planet-on-the-famous-escape-velocity-graph

Comment: @HSharp: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Earth

Comment: @Qami: yes the ppms take escape velocity and RMS into account although again, not perfectly, as a ratio of 6.0 is assumed to hold on to considered substance "forever".

Comment: Glad to hear it! And bounded accuracy is a legitimate part of any simulation.

Comment: @Hal I see, sorry I think I got confused with your post thinking both the big and small planet were supposed to be terrestrial.

Comment: @HSharp no problem :) actually, the lower end of the "super earths" that get generated are actually pretty ... earth like... or venus like or have super dense freezing atmospheres. It's fun, actually/ But this negative Kelvin temperature makes me (rightly!!) question my math... :'[

Answer (score 0):

I think you balanced your equation wrong, try this:

> Tf₂ = 1 / ((1/T₁) - (ln(P₁/P₂) / (-ΔHfus / R)))

Comment: Thanks, will try this. the negative on ΔH is (I think!) when we start from the "P2 over P1" version of the equation. I started from the "P1 over P2" version, which switches the ΔH to positive:

ln(P1/P2) = ΔH/R * (1/T2 - 1/T1)

unless that version is wrong?