# Can an ocean and beach only planet exist with an O2 breathable atmosphere?

Tags: planets, environment

I'm creating a planet, and I want it to be:

- A windy place, with ocean everywhere (like the earth)
- The same pressure & composition at sea level (like the earth)
- Only one biome: A beach. The entire world would be a beach; no matter what land you're on, it's a beach.

Is this possible? If not, what are some alternatives?

Comment: A 'beach', or a desert? Does regolith as on the Moon count? Does finely ground lava rock count? Do you allow volcanoes?

Comment: a beach or a coastal region? If first, then not possible because wave action will eventually wash away the sand, ending with 100% ocean surface of a planet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> thin, sand shorelines, all across the globe

Sand is not a primary rock: it forms by disintegration either of another rock or other hard substances, like shells, glass, etc.

That apart, sand needs a substrate on which it can deposit.

Only for the above reasons, you cannot strictly have what you describe: you will need to have at least some other formation which is eroded to produce the sand and on which the sand itself rests.

Comment: there is also one other method of making sand. Parrot fish https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/sand.html

Comment: Or you can have the silica be biogenically fixed. Very big diatoms?

Comment: but what if there's a *lot* of sand? like, a molten core, layers of hardened lava, then finally sand? I don't know, the erosion of the water against the layers from lower creating sand?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier that's not how sand works, pile it deep enough and it will compress into sand stone or erode into clay.

Answer (score 16):

## Old:

Your world is old and mostly shallow ocean. There is little surface geological activity. Any land there once was eroded away millennia ago.  Ocean currents and wind occasionally stir up the sandy sediment that comprises the sea floor. Those beaches are sand bars that are kicked up until wave and wind action erode them away to nothing.

This is rather like the [coral reef world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/201259/possible-reef-world) proposed in some other questions.

Answer (score 15):

I've read that [something like 70% of Earth's oxygen production is by oceanic photosynthesis](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/ocean-oxygen.html#:%7E:text=At%20least%20half%20of%20Earth%27s,Earth%20comes%20from%20the%20ocean.) (phytoplankton, cyanobacteria, seaweed).  There's no reason this couldn't happen on your beach planet.

However, as @L.Dutch points out, sand has to come from somewhere.  On Earth, sand beaches are usually populated by material carried down by a river, and coastlines with a long way between significant rivers (like much of the coast near the Oregon/California border) tend to have cliffs with their feet in the surf, rather than luxuriant beaches, while others that are prone to very heavy weather (like the southwestern coast of England and Wales) are more likely to have "shingle" -- cobble rock, averaging the size of a fist -- rather than sand.  This also varies depending on the rock type at the coast -- for instance, basalt, as on Hawaiian and California/Oregon/Washington coast, vs. sedimentary rocks as found on most of Great Britain's coastline -- but the bottom line is, if you don't have a source of sand, you won't have what we usually think of as beaches, and if you don't have highlands and rivers, your only reasonable source of sand is direct erosion of rock like the magma rocks of Hawaii, which tend to product black, glassy sand rather than white or tan "beach" sand.

The only alternative I can see is coral sand, which forms on atolls.  The problem with this is that in order to rise above the ocean surface, an atoll needs to have formed on a structure that can rise relative to the ocean, or persist long enough for the ocean level to drop (which likely won't happen on a planet that's all ocean and beach).

Comment: I don't think that "70% of Earth's oxygen production is by oceanic photosynthesis". If you mean 70% of conversion CO2 > O2, then yeah, maybe. But net effect of photosynthesis on atmospheric O2 content is very low (IIRC 0.02%), so not only oxygen in atmosphere must come from somewhere else first, but if there is no substantial fauna as source of CO2, the planet becomes quickly (geologically speaking) lifeless.

Comment: All the oxygen in Earth's atmosphere, plus what oxidized the iron out of the seas in the first place, came originally from cyanobacteria photosynthesis in the ocean.    Also, https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/ocean-oxygen.html#:~:text=At%20least%20half%20of%20Earth's,Earth%20comes%20from%20the%20ocean.

Comment: I do not dispute that, but that was then, this is now. Now we have oxidizing atmosphere, back then it was reducing. As of right now photosynthesis' net oxygen production is near-zero, with phytoplankton being scientifically proven to be very inefficient in that regard, so science needs another source of oxygen we breathe...

Comment: @AcePL Did you read the NOAA article I linked?  Of course "net" oxygen production is near zero, it's just enough to offset consumption (more or less).  But according to the linked article, 50-80% of that is due to oceanic organisms.

Comment: I read the article. But my point is not authoritative one, it's logical: if photosynthesis converts CO2 to O2, it's not possible to create 15% of oxygen out of current 0.04% of CO2, especially using process that's 0.0002% effective...

Comment: @AcePL you're being silly. The entire amount of oxygen in the atmosphere isn't replaced every year. Only a very small fraction of the atmospheric O2 is consumed. This small fraction is replaced, primarily through oceanic photosynthesis. The atmosphere is HUGE. You really think 15% of it is used up every single year?

Comment: @neph - so we're back to my original comment? So you're saying this is about replenishment rate of oxygen in atmosphere? Ok, let's take that, but then there's this: https://www.sciencenews.org/article/phytoplankton-flunk-photosynthesis-efficiency-test, so 70% or even 50-80 is in high doubt, because if, actually, this number is correct, it is WITHIN ocean, which also USES oxygen. I understand that this is an issue of scale, but I am pointing out that oceans release tiny amount of oxygen into atmosphere COMPARED to what is consumed. This equation doesn't balance.

Comment: @AcePL That sounds like you have an opposing answer.  Please post, with references, why you think an ocean can't supply enough excess oxygen production to keep a breathable atmosphere, rather than arguing in comments.

Answer (score 10):

## Yes, if the sand is alive.

Normally, non sand biomes would form. But, if the land is alive, then the sand could just be dominant.

Have the sand be a photosynthetic sort of plant that lucked on some unbeatable strategy during its evolution. Almost everywhere is covered in sand plants, which work as a giant organism to catch the sun and make the world sandy.

## Have no continents.

Your world has seas high enough that any land continents are covered. The only exceptions are mountains and volcano islands, where everyone lives. Everywhere is windy, and everyone can live on islands and island hop.

Answer (score 5):

**Ocean world, mountainous islands**

The crust of your planet has been very buzy. Because of the earthquakes, the surface of the planet looks like a chaotic washboard, mountain ranges everywhere, elongated over 1000km or more. There is also a *lot* of water on your planet, which results in a large ocean, with many, elongated islands. The habitable parts of these islands are the shores. Inland, the islands are vulcanic badlands. Instable grounds, just like the shores are. It is very difficult to build a house that will stand for years. People live on the beaches and a few kilometers up the mountain. When a tsunami comes, they use special roads and elevators to evacuate.

**Sand from friction**

The sand originates from friction: geologic activity over long periods, with crust plates sometimes fragmenting in thousands of pieces, or crashing brutally. This has formed loads of loose sand and pebbles, left on the ocean floor, or bulged upward with another collision. Sometimes, the ocean floor will suddenly rise, locally. On your planet that happens very frequently. Every year, new islands are formed.

**Cause: tidal forces**

The cause of all this rumble: your planet got a new moon, a hundred million years ago. It suddenly appeared, then it stayed.. its orbit is elliptical and twice per month, a varying region will be subject to extreme tidal forces. Not only water goes up, loose parts of the planet crust move along too.

**Big Moon days**

Very inconvenient planet for its inhabitants.. but its Big Moon days draw lots of tourists ! Most tsunami's are quite predictable and seem to be an attraction, rather than a deterrence. The sounds.. it is a thrill to stay on this planet for a few weeks. Backpackers love the outrageous nature. A beautiful view, all these young, pointy and sometimes smoking mountain ranges everywhere.. the lava, the geysers.. And the beaches, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Everybody mentions that sand can't form without being weathered from a primary quartz-bearing igneous rock. That's very true!

But there is biogenic silica--and it actually solves both problems. Not only do [diatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatoms) form silica (quartz) shells, they're also the primary source of oxygen in the modern atmosphere. It's easy to conceive of a world in which diatoms evolved to be much bigger (sand-grain-sized), forming coarse diatomite beaches instead of the fine diatomaceous earth we're used to.

Answer (score 2):

**An almost-water world.**

Yes, it's possible.

The oxygen is no problem at all. Single-celled photosynthetic organisms in the oceans here on Earth generate considerably over half of our oxygen.

The "beach, everywhere" aspect is harder. Plate tectonics as on Earth will always throw up mountains. But a planet with so much water that only the highest of volcanically formed mountains rise only slightly above the surface, is possible. (Using one measure of height, the tallest mountains on Earth are the island volcanoes).

So almost all ocean, with a scattering of coral attols, and coral sand beaches. Realistically, there will probably be a few steep volcanic peaks (active or dormant), as well as a majority of attols surrounding slightly submerged extinct peaks.  No visible continents. Continents like Zealandia may exist, but even more submerged. It's ocean-floor spreading across "hot spots" which thrown up ocean volcanoes and then takes them away from their lava source and support pressure, letting them gently submerge while coral grows upwards as they do.

Altogether, not unlike Earth's Pacific, but everywhere. Almost a water world, but not quite.

Incidentally, the impermanence of these places across geological spans of time, means that all terrestrial life you envisage will have to breed or seed in the oceans, and colonise dry land anew every generation. (Like palm crabs, or coconut palms with their floating seeds).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. All the sand you need can be formed by [parrot fish eating undersea corals and pooping out the skeletons as sand.](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/sand.html)

All the oxygen you need can be produced by photosynthesis of ocean-borne algae.

Your beaches do not have to be "different", they can be exactly like Earth beaches. The oceans can be full of plants, like Earth's oceans, and fish, including sharks, and mammals, like whales and dolphins. Or aquatic dinosaurs. You can have shellfish. Coral reefs. Crabs. Other scavengers of dead fish.

In order to be "all beach everywhere", you probably need a pretty stable ocean level, and fairly small islands with very low elevation.